# Grafana GET /api/orgs/name/:orgName not working if the organization name has "/" character

Tags: grafana, grafana-api

I am using Grafana 8.5.2 version. I want to execute the API to get the organization ID by passing below the organization name

My Organization name :   ABC C/O Tools

When I try to execute the below API, I am getting error as "Not Found". I tried by sending raw and encoded name. but not working.

**API Details:**

GET /api/orgs/name/:orgName

**Note:**  This API is working in my local but not working in the QA and Prod environments which has a valid https.

Could someone suggest me on solving this issue?

Answer (score -1):

I would say don't use plain name: `ABC C/O Tools` but URL encoded value: `ABC%20C%2FO%20Tools`.

It is used also in the example in the doc: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/developers/http_api/org/#get-organization-by-name